# Failing to login or logout with Symfony2 session and Amazon Web Services

Tags: symfony, session, amazon-web-services

i got a project in amazon. Today we split the project with two instances, both instances attack at the same filesystem, they are preceded by a load balancer.

Now we are taking some errors with Forms and login and Logout controllers, some times we got `Invalid CSRF Token` error, sometimes the Login works good. The logout sometimes works but some times doesn't.

Anybody knows why this issue is throwing now? :(

Answer (score 1):

How is the load balancer configured? Is it "session sticky" as nginx states it, meaning the same IP will always go to the same machine?

Does the 2 instances have the same Symfony secret? 
That one is used in some cases to "seed" the CSRF generator.

As a note, storing sessions on the file system is a performance bottleneck. Consider moving those to memcache or similar; then you will be able to share those between your applications. A shared filesystem is not needed but that, and may come with a performance penalty especially for the cache.